# Slow Include query with EF

Tags: entity-framework, sql-execution-plan

Context: The webapplication is some sort of Reddit with Tags.

I have the following include initialisation which returns a IQueryable:

```
 IQueryable<Item> items = itemRepository
            .Include(  //.Actions
            el => el.Votes, 
            el => el.Comments, 
            el => el.CreatedBy.Roles,
            el => el.TagItems.Select(dl => dl.Tag.Actions))
            .Where(el => el.SiteId == siteId && el.Status >= 0)
            .OrderBy(orderBy).AsNoTracking();
```

The IQueryable is later used with ExpressionBuilder (LinqKit), because there are a lot of AND / OR queries.

When i use the personal mode on my application ( = show only results that a user upvoted/created or results from the tags that the user is following), the query becomes really slow:

```
 if (filterBy.PersonalMode)
        {
            //    || el.TagItems.Any(dl => dl.Tag.UserId == filterBy.UserId)
            itemPredicate = itemPredicate.And(el =>
        el.Votes.Select(dl => new { UserId = dl.UserId}).Any(dl => 
        dl.UserId == filterBy.UserId)
        || el.CreatedById == filterBy.UserId
        || (filterBy.RoleId.HasValue && el.TagItems.Select(dl => new {   UserRoleId = dl.Tag.UserRoleId, PersonalTags = dl.Tag.PersonalTags }).Any(dl => dl.UserRoleId.HasValue && filterBy.RoleId.HasValue && dl.UserRoleId.Value == filterBy.RoleId.Value))
        || el.TagItems.Any(dl => dl.Tag.PersonalTags.Select(cl => new { UserId = cl.UserId }).Any(cl => cl.UserId == filterBy.UserId)));

        }
```

I'm trying to stay away from alternatives from EF, because it keeps my code pretty clean to read.

The query itselve, mentions a 61% execution time.

Execution plan XML:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry9najEMr

Slow part:

*Output list*

```
[handlr].[dbo].[Tags].Id; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].Name; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].SiteId; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].Active; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].CreatedOn; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].FillsInParentTag; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].ShowOnOverview; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].ParentTagId; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].LeftBower; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].RightBower; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].Depth; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].Caption; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].isRestricted; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].Description; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].ShowTag; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].Count; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].UserId; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].UserRoleId; [handlr].[dbo].[Tags].SynonymOfTagId
```

Visual:
[image: Execution plan]

Any advice on how to improve this query? Adding non-clustured indexes don't seem to do much currently.

Comment: Here's the paste the plan version: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ry9najEMr

Comment: Updated the link, thanks